# alphanumeric regular expression in R

Tags: regex, r, alphanumeric

I am trying to use [:alnum:] as explained on ?regex

Anyone knows why

```
grepl("^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([;])", x="dj5sads;adsa")
```

returns TRUE, but

```
grepl("^([:alnum:])+([;])", x="dj5sads;adsa")
```

returns FALSE?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`[:alnum:]` is only the *name* of the class. As you want to put this *named class* into a character class, you have to enclose it with just another pair of `[]`:

```
[[:alnum:]]
```

In your example it'd be

```
grepl("^([[:alnum:]])+([;])", x="dj5sads;adsa")    
//Output: TRUE
```

[demo @ ideone](http://ideone.com/W5G6B3)

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to remember for next time

Comment: @RockScience you're welcome. I hope it's clear, that this applies to all of the named classes (`[:alnum:]`, `[:alpha:]`, `[:blank:]`, and so on)!

Comment: I came here bc I was wondering why `\\w` does not work. Then I found out it's possible with `perl = TRUE`.

Answer (score 2):

what you want is

```
grepl("^([[:alnum:]])+([;])", x="dj5sads;adsa")
```

remember we put the `SearchPattern`

Comment: Thanks! And sorry you are a few seconds late ;)