# Compare patterns of text in R

Tags: r, matching

I want find out whether a string matches a certain pattern. For some reason “regexpr(regexp, s)”, always returns TRUE (see code below). Anybody familiar with this R feature?

```
regexp <- "[:digit:]{4} [:alpha:]{2} [:digit:]{5}"
s <- "6123LM32227"
regexpr(regexp, text=s)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297141/alphanumeric-regular-expression-in-r) on Stack Overflow. Please check for answers before posting.

The TRUE value you are seeing relates to the useBytes attribute, a flag to distinguish matching on bytes or characters (see ?regexpr)

```
regexpr("[[:digit:]]{4}[[:alpha:]]{2}[[:digit:]]{5}", "6123LM32227")

[1] 1
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 11
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

works fine.

Comment: Hi Goangit, Thank you for responding. When I change the content of s (e.g. remove the M), I get the same result. So I still don't know wether s matches the pattern. What am I doing wrong? Best regards, Fred.

Comment: That's fine @Fred. For future reference, the usual etiquette is to click Accepted when an answer solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to obtain a logical vector indicating matches, you have to use `grepl` instead. Furthermore, you have to use `[[:digit:]]`, not `[:digit:]`. Finally, you should omit the spaces in your regex, since they match spaces literally.

```
regexp <- "[[:digit:]]{4}[[:alpha:]]{2}[[:digit:]]{5}"
s <- "6123LM32227"
grepl(regexp, s)
# [1] TRUE
```